# SQL Computed Column used in queries causing performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns A,B,C and another table with column username.

In column C i have a function getName(A).

getName(A) is roughly

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetName] (
    @name VARCHAR(100)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @nextWord VARCHAR(100);
    SET @retval = @name

    IF EXISTS (Select 1 from someTable where username = SUSER_NAME())
    BEGIN
    SET @name = Replace(Replace(Replace(RTRIM(LTRIM(@name)),',',' ,'),'(','( '),')',' )')
    SET @retval = LEFT(@name, 1);
        WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 1) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @name = LTRIM(RIGHT(@name, LEN(@name) - CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 1)));

            IF CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 1) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @nextWord = LTRIM(LEFT(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 1) - 1))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @nextWord = @name
            END

            SET @retval += ' ' + CASE 
                    WHEN @nextWord IN (
                            'List'
                            ,'Of'
                            ,'Different'
                            ,'Words'
                            )
                        THEN @nextWord
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(@nextWord) = 1
                        THEN @nextWord
                    WHEN ISDATE(@nextWord) = 1
                        THEN @nextWord
                    ELSE LEFT(@nextWord, 1)
                    END
        END
    END

    RETURN @retval;
END
```

Now when I try to use column C in queries it basically times out.  Trying to figure out if there is a way to make it faster.  If the computed function for C is just referencing A it runs normal.  but when its either choose A or choose the first letter of each word in A along with words in the allowed list it goes slow.  If I make this function true always it goes relatively quick.  I tried with the exists and still it is not fast.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I updated the function above. I should note, when the EXISTS query returns True it runs quickly, when it returns false it runs slow.  That is the bigger dilemma that I am confused about.

Comment: It's horrible! Start by never using that ISNULL approach again, you can do better with a simple EXISTS. To really help here avoid using inline functions like it on your selects. If necessary create a view a join with it.  Also see if don't got indexes problems on your queries

Comment: Anyway it's just returning the `@name` first char if if can be find in someTable and the entire `@name` otherwise. It seens utterly dumb

Comment: Ok, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Kevin . . . The title is pretty clear.  The OP wants to create a computed column with the formula, which -- as arcane as it is -- must meet some local requirement.  You cannot create a computed column that directly references another table, so the function is necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess I should have been more clear.  I think this could be an instance of an XY problem.  I'm trying to avoid it and find out what OP actually needs, rather than answer the problem as asked.

Comment: @Kevin We want to set up a situation where we can have a table that contains usernames. Where in if it is that username we want to basically anonymize the words while leaving a certain subset allowed to be full words.  Now we used to have column C only, I renamed C to A and created a new column C to be a function of A.  I did it this way because we have a ton of other things that reference C already and we don't want to have to change everything in order to accomodate that.  Hope that helps answer the need.

Comment: You have loops, selects, replaces, trims, case expressions, and million other things in your function, which will be called once per each row. You will never, never, never be able to optimize this unlees you change whole approach.

Comment: But what I was saying is it runs okay when it actually goes through.  When the username doesn't exist in someTable that is when it runs slow.  But that should be the time when it runs faster because it doesn't have to go through.

Comment: Do you have an index on someTable for the username column

Comment: @Kevin yea I added an index, but someTable only has 1 column(username) and currently in the table is only 1 row.  I don't anticipate that table growing past 5-10 records, but I added the index just in case it would still help performance.  It didn't though.

Answer (score 2):

This is, alas, a very reasonable function, because it is the only way to create a computed column that references another table.

The following code is safer:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE @retval VARCHAR(100);

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM someTable WHERE username = SUSER_NAME)
    BEGIN
        SET @retval = LEFT(@name, 1);
    END
    ELSE SET @retval = @name;
    RETURN @retval;
END
```

The `isnull()` method is clever, but the original code would generate an error if there were multiple rows in the table that matched the `where` condition.  Also, it requires considering all values in the table, rather than just the first.  `EXISTS` knows to stop at the first matching row.

You want an index on `sometable(username)`.  You can do this either by creating a unique constraint or by creating the index explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible to use an inline function (rather than multi statement) instead?  Might help the RBARness of it all, though still require horrendous scans if searched against.

Comment: @MatBailie Not sure an inline function is possible for this because it references another table. Gordon, I changed my query to Exists instead of ISNULL but the username is the only column in the table and it is set as a PK so there shouldn't be duplicates, but it seems the advantage to Exists is it stops when finding it where as this would continue through the table searching.  There is only going to be a few records in this table though.

Comment: @Jerry . . . A primary key has an index, so the `exists` is a fast index lookup.  Even if the engine ignored the unique constraint, it would peak ahead at the next value and only return one.  I'm guessing that the overhead is in the function itself.  I would suggest you write this as a view instead of a computed column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How can I do this as a view? The dilemma is we have an existing column(columnName) name that is referenced by reports and scripts and many other things.  What I did was create a column called columnNameActual and now have columnName reference the function that returns either columnNameActual or the first letter of each word in columnNameActual.  We have too many things referencing columnName in order to change them all to reference the view instead. So I figured changing it to a computed column would be fine, but the performance is poor and I want to see how to fix that.

Comment: @Jerry  . . . I don't know what you mean by "use this in a view".  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You suggested writing this as a view instead of a computed column.  Right now we have a column lets call it personName.  Many things reference personName, queries, views, ssrs reports, code.  I want personName to now be versatile to be the value generated from the function.  So I made a column personNameActual and made personName = getName(personNameActual) and that returns personName or first initials of the names.  How would you best handle doing that?